# How to updateProfile for phoneNumber for an email/password account in firebase with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting to the success block as everything goes well, but then when I check the user it seems as if the user never got updated. I have this working for displayName, but for some reason phoneNumber is not working.

Here is the code:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  user
  .updateProfile({ phoneNumber: '01112223333' })
  .then(() => {
   alert('success');
   console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(err => {
   alert(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [updatePhoneNumber](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber) method of User.

Comment: Do you know what the `phoneCredential` wants?

Comment: var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId, verificationCode);

check this one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider

Comment: Mk yeah I found it thank you if I get this working I will accept answer and most likely add an edit of what I did and you can accept edit.